# When is the Ito representation deterministic?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider a functional on Wiener space $F\in L^2(\Omega, \Bbb R)$. Then by Ito's representation theorem we have that $$F=E[F]+\int_0^T\phi(s)dB(s)$$ for some nice $\phi$. Question, when is $\phi$ deterministic? I know that if $\phi$ is deterministic then $F$ must be Gaussian as the Ito integral of a deterministic function is Gaussian.

However is the converse true? If $F\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ can we find a deterministic $\phi$ so that $$F=\mu+\int_0^T \phi(s) dB(s)$$

What about just letting $\phi(s)\equiv \sigma/\sqrt{T}$?

Comment: If we choose $\phi(s)=\sigma/\sqrt{T}$, then the right-hand side has the same distribution as $F$. However, it is not necessarily almost surely equal to $F$... because otherwise it would follow that $F=\mu + \int_0^T \phi(s) \, dB_s = G$ almost surely for **any** two $F,G \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: @saz Ito's representation theorem is a statement about almost sure equality, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the integrand $\phi$ depends really on $F$ and not only on the distribution of $F$. If you prefer a concrete example: take $F=B_1+B_2$ and $T=2$, then $\phi(s) =1_{(1,2]}(s)+ 2 \cdot 1_{(0,1]}(s)$ (... which is different from the function, which you suggested).

Comment: @saz Thank you for your comments. Slightly off topic question, Girsanov density also exists almost surely, right? I.e. not in distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:** Take 
$$
\phi(s) = \cases{ 1,&  $0\le s\le T/2$;\cr \xi,& $T/2<s\le T$.\cr}
$$
where $\xi$ is the sign of $B_{T/2}$. This $\phi$ is non-deterministic.  But, using the facts that $\xi$ is (i) $\mathcal F_{T/2}$ measurable and therefore (ii) independent of the post-$T/2$ increments of the Brownian motion,  one can check that $F=\int_0^T\phi(s)\,dB_s=B_{T/2}+\xi\cdot(B_T-B_{T/2})$ has the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $T$.